# Very slow performance on RecyclerView with ConstraintLayout and inside ViewPager on Android

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have a **RecyclerView** with about 20 items. It takes long time to render and blocks de UI.

I am using **ConstraintLayout** for positioning items in each row. They are not complicated as you can see in the screenshots - [Link to animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFaWo.gif).

I also have a **ViewPager** for main navigation (See bottom bar). On each page Fragment there is also a ViewPager. In this inner ViewPager is where you find the RecyclerView (inside a NestedScrollView).

Additionally I have a scroll listener on the NestedScrollView to do a parallax effect on the header.

**I notice that if I remove some of the items and have the RecyclerView with only 3 items, it becomes a lot more faster. So it really seems to be some problem with the rows of the RecyclerView.**

**I also made a test and replace the ConstraintLayout of each row with a FrameLayout with fixed height - The performance was the same**

I am also using **Iconics** (for font icon) and **Calligraphy** (for custom typography) - Can this be affecting the performance ?

---

### **Preview:**

Notice the circle when i'm trying to scroll immediately after changing to the first page and the UI is blocked. Also notice that the ViewPager slides when going to the second page but when coming from the second to the first it just blocks the animation and the list appears immediately.

[Link to animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFaWo.gif)

**Row Item** (history_item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="12 JUN"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xs"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_small"/>

        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/date"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/kms"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="{evz_workout_running}"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:gravity="left" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xs"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBlack"
            android:text="325,4"
            android:translationY="-12dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/kms_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/kms"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/kms"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="KMS"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"/>




        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView
            android:id="@+id/icon_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/kms"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_speed"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_xs"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_medium"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            android:text="{evz_config_duration}"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/icon_time"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"
            android:text="00:00:07"/>



        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView
            android:id="@+id/icon_speed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_points"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
            android:paddingTop="2sp"
            android:paddingBottom="2sp"
            android:text="{evz_rate}"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_speed"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/icon_speed"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/icon_speed"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"
            android:text="00'00''"/>


        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView
            android:id="@+id/icon_points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/icon_time"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/icon_speed"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_small"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:text="{evz_star}"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/points"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/icon_points"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/icon_points"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/icon_points"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"
            android:text="3500"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/undo_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
            android:textAppearance="@style/textStyleBold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="Anular"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment that has the RecyclerView (pager_fragment.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <merge
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sub_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="210dp">

                <pt.sportzone.everyzone.ui.DynamicViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/sub_pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/sub_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            ...


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</merge>
```

And the Fragment class (PagerFragment.java):

```
public class PagerFragment extends Fragment implements IPagerFragment, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Get elements from Layout
        mPager = (DynamicViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_pager);

        if (mButton1 != null && mButton2 != null && mButton3 != null) {
```

...

```
            if (mHeader != null) {
                // Listen to when tree is ready so we can setup parallax
                mHeader.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        mHeader.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        setupParallax();
                    }
                });
            }
        }


        if (mPager != null) mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        activate();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (!isVisibleToUser) activated = false;
        active = isVisibleToUser;
    }

    protected void activate() {
        if (active && getView() != null && getActivity() != null && !activated) {
            activated = true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mPager == null) return;

        //Log.d(EZ.TAG, "Page Selected: " + position);
        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (FragmentPagerAdapter) mPager.getAdapter();
        targetPosition = position;
        IPagerFragment fragmentAppear = (IPagerFragment) adapter.getItem(targetPosition);
        IPagerFragment fragmentDisappear = (IPagerFragment) adapter.getItem(currentPosition);
        fragmentDisappear.willDisappear(targetPosition);
        fragmentAppear.willAppear(currentPosition);

        mButton1.setSelected(false);
        mButton2.setSelected(false);
        mButton3.setSelected(false);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mButton1.setSelected(true);
                break;
            case 1:
                mButton2.setSelected(true);
                break;
            case 2:
                mButton3.setSelected(true);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if (mPager == null) return;

        //Log.d(EZ.TAG, position + " - " + positionOffset + " - " + positionOffsetPixels);
        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = (FragmentPagerAdapter) mPager.getAdapter();
        //currentPosition = position;
        if (position == targetPosition && positionOffsetPixels == 0) {
            IPagerFragment fragmentAppear = (IPagerFragment) adapter.getItem(targetPosition);
            IPagerFragment fragmentDisappear = (IPagerFragment) adapter.getItem(currentPosition);
            currentPosition = targetPosition;
            fragmentDisappear.didDisappear();
            fragmentAppear.didAppear();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void setupParallax() {

        // Listen for scroll events
        if (scrollChangedListener == null) {

            // Get initial data
            initialWidth = mBackground.getWidth();
            initialHeight = mBackground.getHeight();
            initialRatio = initialHeight / initialWidth;
            curveInitialHeight = mCurve.getHeight();

            if (mScroll != null && collapseHeader) {
                mScroll.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                        doParallax(v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY);
                    }
                });
            }

            UI.flattenConstraintRatio(mBackground);
            UI.flattenConstraintRatio(mBackgroundSpacer);
            UI.flattenConstraintRatio(mCurve);

            mCurve.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            // Run first parallax iteration
            doParallax(mScroll, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        }
    }

    public void doParallax(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

        // No height, something's wrong, just go away
        if (initialHeight == 0) return;

        // Get the percentage of scroll till hitting the max scroll target (initial Height)
        float percent = (float)scrollY / curveInitialHeight;

        float percentLeft = 1 - percent;

        if (percent < 0) percent = 0;
        if (percent > 1) percent = 1;

        float percentFast = Math.min(percent * 1.4f, 1);
        float percentLeftFast = 1 - percentFast;

        // Adjust the profile background image
        int headerHeight = Math.max((int)initialHeight - (int)(percent * curveInitialHeight), (int)initialHeight - (int)curveInitialHeight); // 24 -> status bar, 53 -> action bar
        UI.setConstraintHeight(mBackground, headerHeight);
        int curveHeight = Math.max((int)(percentLeft * curveInitialHeight), 0);
        UI.setConstraintHeight(mCurve, curveHeight);


        if (mButton1 != null) {
            mButton1.getButtonLabel().setAlpha(percentLeft);
            mButton2.getButtonLabel().setAlpha(percentLeft);
            mButton3.getButtonLabel().setAlpha(percentLeft);
        }

        // Adjust Elements alpha
        //mBackground.getDrawable().setAlpha((int)(percentLeftFast * 255));
        //mGradient.setAlpha(percentLeft);

    }
```

And the Adapter (HistoryAdapter.java):

```
public class HistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final int PENDING_REMOVAL_TIMEOUT = 3000; // 3sec

private Fragment fragment;

List<Music> items;
List<Music> itemsPendingRemoval;
boolean undoOn;

private Handler handler = new Handler(); // hanlder for running delayed runnables
HashMap<Music, Runnable> pendingRunnables = new HashMap<>(); // map of items to pending runnables, so we can cancel a removal if need be

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    Music track;

    public TextView mDate;
    public IconicsTextView mIcon;
    public TextView mKms;
    public IconicsTextView mIconTime;
    public TextView mTime;
    public IconicsTextView mIconSpeed;
    public TextView mSpeed;
    public IconicsTextView mIconPoints;
    public TextView mPoints;
    public ConstraintLayout mContainer;
    public Button mUndo;

    OnHistoryItemClickedListener mListener;

    public ViewHolder(Fragment fragment, View holder) {
        super(holder);

        // Force interface implementation
        if (fragment instanceof OnHistoryItemClickedListener) {
            mListener = (OnHistoryItemClickedListener) fragment;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(fragment.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHistoryItemClickedListener");
        }
        mContainer = (ConstraintLayout) holder.findViewById(R.id.container);
        mDate = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.date);
        mIcon = (IconicsTextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        mKms = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.kms);
        mIconTime = (IconicsTextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.icon_time);
        mTime = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.time);
        mIconSpeed = (IconicsTextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.icon_speed);
        mSpeed = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.speed);
        mIconPoints = (IconicsTextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.icon_points);
        mPoints = (TextView) holder.findViewById(R.id.points);

        mUndo = (Button) holder.findViewById(R.id.undo_button);

        mContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mContainer) {
            mListener.onHistoryItemClicked(this.getLayoutPosition(), track);
        }
    }

}

public interface OnHistoryItemClickedListener {
    void onHistoryItemClicked(int position, Music music);
    void onHistoryItemRemoved(int position, Music music);
}

public HistoryAdapter(Fragment fragment, List<Music> items) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.items = items;
    this.itemsPendingRemoval = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
public HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) fragment.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View track = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_item, parent, false);
    return new HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder(fragment, track);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(HistoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Music item = items.get(position);

    if (itemsPendingRemoval.contains(item)) {
        // we need to show the "undo" state of the row
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        //holder.titleTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.mUndo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mUndo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // user wants to undo the removal, let's cancel the pending task
                Runnable pendingRemovalRunnable = pendingRunnables.get(item);
                pendingRunnables.remove(item);
                if (pendingRemovalRunnable != null) handler.removeCallbacks(pendingRemovalRunnable);
                itemsPendingRemoval.remove(item);
                // this will rebind the row in "normal" state
                notifyItemChanged(items.indexOf(item));
            }
        });
    } else {
        // we need to show the "normal" state
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        //holder.titleTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        //holder.titleTextView.setText(item);
        holder.mUndo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.mUndo.setOnClickListener(null);
    }

    holder.track = item;

    if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
        holder.mContainer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragment.getContext(), R.drawable.row_with_arrow_no_border));
    } else {
        holder.mContainer.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(fragment.getContext(), R.drawable.row_with_arrow));
    }
}

...
```

Where I add items to the adapter (as for testing I use a postDelayed runnable to simulate loading time)

```
private void dataLoaded() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // specify an adapter (see also next example)
                if (getView() != null) {
                    mAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(MainActivityHistoryFragment.this, data.getTracks());
                    mAdapter.setUndoOn(true);
                    mHistory.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                }
            }
        }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post where/when you are loading your data into the adapter?

Comment: I just added the part of the adapter. Please let me know if you want more info. data is a class that has an array list of music tracks (testing). Each track is a class with a few fields. Additionally, I tried to double the number of items and it now takes a lifetime to render the RecyclerView.

Comment: @Luis, So did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should not be creating a new adapter each time you load data. This might be the cause of your delay. Instead try adding a method to swap/reset the data on an existing adapter, call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. See [this example](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_defaultadapter) for more information.

Comment: This is only called 1 time when the fragment is created. Anyway, this would not explain the rendering time with just a few items on the first load. If I double the items it just becomes incredibly slow - first time.

Comment: Ok if you are only calling this one time, it shouldn't be an issue. My gut is saying it is a problem with your adapter. Maybe try simplifying the layout and see if it is still slow, (perhaps make your viewholder just a text view).

Comment: I did that and placed 300 items on the array. It binds them all at load time in the adapter. Shouldn't it be loading just the visible items?

Comment: can you try initializing your adapter before adding the events? Maybe in onCreateView(), and just give it an empty list. Then in the `dataLoaded` update the adapter, and call dataset changed.I can't really tell your exact issue, but this is how I do my list with complicated views and it renders fast.